# How to provide a value for C++ interface members?

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to program against an API that was written for C++ and need to migrate certain concepts over to C# that will run on an embedded system.

I have a description of an interface method that goes:

```
HRESULT ConnecTo (string deviceAddress, int32_t connectionTimeout, IVideohub ** videoHubDevice)
```

The first two members are easy enough to satisfy but I get a little hazy when it tells me that the last member is an out that will return a object interface for the unit I will be connecting to.

Is this a pointer to the object interface on the server side?  If my question is clear enough can someone be so kind as to provide an example of how they would implement this interface method in C#?

Comment: last element would be `ref  IVideohub videoHubDevice`

Comment: thanks! I did think about that but wasn't sure. can I ask more questions in this thread or do I have accept the answer and post a new question?

Comment: There is no answer, so nothing to accept here. You can edit your question to ask additional or new questions, but make sure they haven't been asked before. So do a search first.

Answer (score 0):

```
IVideoHub videoHubDevice;
HRESULT ConnecTo(string deviceAddress, int connectionTimeout, out IVideoHub videoHubDevice)
```

Comment: That is not correct, it should be `ref`, as already mentioned in comments.

Comment: Explain why that would matter in C#. Wouldn´t the only difference be that you would have to instantiate IVideoHub first (as described)?

Comment: So, you don't know what the other side of the method does, right?

Comment: Are you talking about the implementation of `ConnectTo` ?

Comment: Yes, I do. The `**` doesn't automatically mean `out`, right?

Comment: Well, I would argue that in C# and in this case, it would be just as good to use `out` as `ref`and many would recommend using out because of the marshalling impact `ref`has when moving it across processes and `ref`should be used only when the initial value sent to the method - in this case ConnectTo is of importance (i.e. if the videoHubDevice should have an inital value that is used by the ConnectTo method). But @PatrickHofman has a point, I am just assuming the the ConnectTo method will instantiate and return an instance of `IVideoHub`, and if so, I would recommend `out`.

Comment: It is actually an unsigned 32 bit int, but isn´t there a C# enum equivalent?

Comment: I'm moving up from embedded systems to OS level apps so alot of this stuff is new to me.